# OpenMP thread respawn

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have a class with a lot of math functions which use OpenMP to parallize for loops. Each time I call one of these class functions a team of threads is spawned, do their work and will be removed.
Is there a possibility to avoid thread destruction and respawning? Can I keep the threads alive and assign them to another function or something? The number of threads does not change during runtime.

Comment: You're referring to threads pools, where threads are created just once and reused as needed. I think this is not part of the OpenMP specification so it would be defined by the implementation. A somewhat relevant answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254882/how-to-reuse-omp-thread-pool-created-by-main-thread-in-worker-thread)

Comment: Threads are created at the start of a parallel section. So you can have a large parallel section and several #omp for or #omp task to reuse the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP does not define what an OpenMP implementation does with the worker threads.  The way the multi-threading is implemented fully depends on the target OS and the quality of the OpenMP implementation.

A reasonable OpenMP implementation will use a thread pool as mentioned in the comments.  That means after the threads have been spawned for the first parallel region (that may happen even before calling `main()`) the threads will kept alive as much as possible.  LL VM's and Intel's OpenMP implementations keep the threads active in a spin loop after a parallel region has ended, so that the runtime saves the expensive thread wake-up from the OS.

If you give more details about what OpenMP implementation you are targeting, I might be able to recommend some more tuning parameters.

**EDIT:** Added some more information how to generally control the waiting behavior.

OpenMP Version 3.0 introduced the environment variable `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` that controls whether or not threads shall enter a spin-wait after a parallel region ends.  If the variable is set to `active`, the threads spin wait and thus consume CPU cycles.  Set to `passive` the threads don't spin, but wait for an OS signal, yield the processor, or the like to wake up for the next parallel region.  The variable also affects waiting for locks and barrier completion.

OpenMP Version 5.0 defines the `omp_pause_resource()` and `omp_pause_resource_all()` API routines.  The idea is to "shutdown" enough of OpenMP so that the OpenMP implementation does not take resources away from threads that have been spawned by other parallel libraries or languages.  One exemplary application is that after a OpenMP parallel regions ends, OpenMP can be shutdown, and a new parallel region with C++ threads can consume all of the machine.  The `omp_pause_resource()` routine stops OpenMP on a particular device, while `omp_pause_resource_all()` stops OpenMP on all devices.  The calls define two levels: `omp_pause_soft` for which OpenMP state is preserved when OpenMP resumes execution later on, and `omp_pause_hard` for which the OpenMP implementation has to reinitialized from scratch when resuming OpenMP.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 C++ compile and my target OS is Windows.

Comment: With VS 2017 you are tied to an OpenMP implementation that only supports OpenMP Version 2.0.  So, you won't have all the nice goodies that control the things you're asking for and that we have put in OpenMP 4.0 and later.  Anyways, VS should keep the threads alive after a parallel region ends, but what exactly they are doing.